# Improving the performance of the following TSQL code

Tags: t-sql, sybase

I am using Sybase DB with TSQL.

The follow snippet of TSQL code is very simple and I need to perform it several 100,000 times (large database) so I would really like to improve its performance in any way possible:

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION
INSERT INTO
  DESTINATION_TABLE
SELECT
  COLUMNS
FROM
  SOURCE_TABLE
WHERE
  ORDER_ID = @orderId

DELETE FROM
  SOURCE_TABLE
WHERE
  ORDER_ID = @orderId
COMMIT TRANSACTION
```

As one can see, I am inserting and removing the same set of rows based on the same condition.

Is there a way to improve the performance of this simple query?

Thanks.

Comment: If you want the transaction to be at the orderId level then not going to get much better.   I would not delete from the source without verification the insert inserted one row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are inserting more than a few rows, you really need to do a bulk insert.  Calling this method 100,000 times, passing it an ID every time, is a linear-processing mindset.   Databases are for set operations.

Construct a temporary table of ID's that you need to insert and delete.   Then do a bulk insert by joining on the ID's in that table, and similarly a bulk delete.

Comment: To my understanding a `View` is essentially a temporary table. Will creating a `View` in this case work? Or do I only need to create a temporary table with one column to add in the IDs?

Comment: Then going back to my original issue, even if I pass in a table, I would have to perform the same join 2 times, one for `INSERT INTO` and one for `DELETE FROM`. Is there a way to improve this?